# Model Data Aren't Displayed in UI

Tags: sapui5

I have developed an SAP UI5 app with JS-Views and JSON Models. Data from the database will be displayed. But now I made a login-view for my app. In the button press function, I'll copy the data of the actual user in a **temp** model and navigate to a launchpad. The launchpad will be rendered, but without considering the data from my **temp** model. First use of this model data should be the management of visible tiles in the launchpad (depending on actual user).
In the launchpad.view.js the data will be logged as "Null".

```
var container = new sap.m.TileContainer({
tiles : [
    new sap.m.StandardTile({
        id : "id",
        icon : "sap-icon://customer",
        title : "{i18n>tileTitle}",
        visible : 
        {
            path : "TempModel>bUsergroup_Admin"},
            formatter : function(bUsergroup) {
                console.log(bUsergroup);
                return bUsergroup;
            }
        }
    }),
]});
```

The model data can be successfully logged in the function *onInit*, *onBeforeRendering*, and *onAfterRendering* on the launchpad controller.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The notation of the path was wrong. There was a missing '/' ...

```
path : "TempModel>/bUsergroup_Admin"},
```